# The button is not processed Unity3D - Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, onclick

The button is not processed when it is clicked, although the script to the button is connected, the method is called, but the application does not stop using breakpoint when the button is clicked, what could be the problem?
Unity 3.1f1

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

Comment: If you are actually using Unity 3.1f1, I suggest you update. That thing is very old that I am even surprised it opens at-all. If you update and still have issues then post your code in your question and a screenshot o where you put the breakpoint that's not working

Comment: Can you post your code? Its hard to guess the problem by just reading your description .

Comment: @Programmer Does not show an error, or shows that I pressed the button. I added screenshots, I changed the version of Unity